# React - Redux fetch data onclick and rerender

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Good day! I wanna to do dynamic dropdown menu, witch get data from server. So, if menu item clicked i wanna to fetch data from server and render result in list. Like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {fetchData} from 'actions'

class MenuItem extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        isOpened: false,
    }
}

toggleOpen() {
    this.props.fetchData(); // Here is fetching data using redux-thunk
    this.setState({isOpened: !this.state.isOpened});
}

render() {
    const {data} = this.props;

    return (
            <a href="#" className="left-menu__link"
               {...( this.state.isOpened && {
                   className: "left-menu__link is-opened"
               } )}
               onClick={(e) => {
                   e.preventDefault();
                   this.toggleOpen.bind(this)();
               }}>

            <ul className="left-menu__sub-level">
                {!R.isEmpty(data) && data.map((item) =>
                    <li item={item} key={item.id}/>)}
            </ul>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    data: getData(state), // get data from state
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    fetchData
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MenuItem)
```

So can you tell me which is the best way to do this?

Comment: return a promise from thunk action, and in the callback set isOpened state

Answer (score 0):

Here I have changed some of the code. I hope it will help

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {fetchData} from 'actions'

class MenuItem extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isOpened: false
        }

        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    }

    handleClick(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        this.setState({isOpened: !this.state.isOpened})
        this.props.fetchData().then((response) => {
            ....
            ....
        })
    }

    render() {
        const {data} = this.props;
        const className = !this.state.isOpened ? 'left-menu__link' : 'left-menu__link is-opened'

        return (
                <a href="#" className={className}
                   onClick={this.handleClick}>

                <ul className="left-menu__sub-level">
                    {!R.isEmpty(data) && data.map((item) =>
                        <li item={item} key={item.id}/>)}
                </ul>
        )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    data: getData(state), // get data from state
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    fetchData
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MenuItem)
```